# Dynamically Pivot latest 5 days production

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How could I turn this table

PRODUCTION TABLE

| Date | Cow ID | Shift | Litres | Production |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | MORN | 5 | P103 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | NOON | 5 | P104 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18415 | NIGHT | 5 | P105 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | MORN | 10 | P106 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | NOON | 11 | P107 |
| 19/07/2021 | 18419 | NIGHT | 6 | P108 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | MORN | 8 | P109 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | NOON | 12 | P110 |
| 12/07/2021 | 18415 | NIGHT | 3 | P111 |

Into this table below. I want the latest 5 production dates data aggregated over all three shifts and pivoted next to each other so I can compare production totals for various days for each cow. Columns sorted from most recent to less recent from left to right.

| Cow ID | 19-Jul-21 | 12-Jul-21 | 5-Jul-21 | 28-Jun-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18415 | 21 | 25 | 24 | 22 |
| 18413 | 30 | 25 | 24 | 22 |
| 18419 | 27 | 25 | 26 | 21 |

I have been able to aggregate the table to daily production. But can't progress further with the Pivoting of Dates into columns.

```
SELECT
     SUM(t.Prod) AS Prod,
     t.Date AS Prod_Date,
     t.Cow_ID AS Cow_ID
FROM (  SELECT*
FROM  PRODUCTION_TABLE) AS  t 
GROUP BY t.Prod_Date, Cow_ID
ORDER BY Prod_Date DESC
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Camile, I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL for this.

```
DECLARE @sql   nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @cols1 nvarchar(256) = N'',
        @cols2 nvarchar(256) = N'';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (5) Date FROM dbo.PRODUCTION_TABLE
  GROUP BY Date
  ORDER BY Date DESC
)
SELECT @cols1 += N',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),x.Date)),
       @cols2 += N',''' + CONVERT(char(10), x.Date) + '''' FROM x;

SELECT @cols1 = STUFF(@cols1, 1, 1, N''),
       @cols2 = STUFF(@cols2, 1, 1, N'');
  
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT [Cow ID],' + @cols1 + ' FROM 
(
  SELECT Date, [Cow ID], Litres
  FROM dbo.Production_Table
  WHERE Date IN (' + @cols2 + ')
) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(Litres) FOR Date IN (' + @cols1 + ')) AS p';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=dbd199de6690b7665147dd380154b90f)

Note that with this approach, there's no guarantee about the order of the columns. If you want to be sure (and you are on SQL Server 2017+), you can use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
DECLARE @sql   nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @cols1 nvarchar(256) = N'',
        @cols2 nvarchar(256) = N'';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (5) Date FROM dbo.PRODUCTION_TABLE
  GROUP BY Date
  ORDER BY Date DESC
)
SELECT @cols1 += STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),x.Date)), N',') 
                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Date DESC),
       @cols2 += STRING_AGG(N'''' + CONVERT(char(10), x.Date) + '''',',')
                 -- order doesn't matter for the PIVOT columns
  FROM x;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT [Cow ID],' + @cols1 + ' FROM 
(
  SELECT Date, [Cow ID], Litres
  FROM dbo.Production_Table
  WHERE Date IN (' + @cols2 + ')
) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(Litres) FOR Date IN (' + @cols1 + ')) AS p';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=418c79d4cf6e30d7100b1bb4da1a4ec3)

If the order is crucial and you're not on SQL Server 2017, you can search for using `FOR XML PATH` to build the column list. Please (always) specify the version in your question (by using an appropriate version-specific tag), so we don't have to guess or make assumptions.

And if you really insist on using regional, language-specific column headers in the output, you can do this (however I recommend doing this kind of translation at the presentation layer):

```
DECLARE @sql   nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @cols1 nvarchar(256) = N'',
        @cols2 nvarchar(256) = N'',
        @cols3 nvarchar(512) = N'';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (5) Date FROM dbo.PRODUCTION_TABLE
  GROUP BY Date
  ORDER BY Date DESC
)
SELECT @cols1 += STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),x.Date)), N',') 
                 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Date DESC),
       @cols2 += STRING_AGG(N'''' + CONVERT(char(10), x.Date) + '''',','),
                 -- order doesn't matter for the PIVOT columns
       @cols3  += STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(REPLACE(
                    CONVERT(char(9),x.Date,6),' ','-')) + ' = ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(char(10),x.Date)), N',' + char(10))
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM x;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT [Cow ID],' + @cols3 + ' 
FROM 
(
  SELECT Date, [Cow ID], Litres
  FROM dbo.Production_Table
  WHERE Date IN (' + @cols2 + ')
) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(Litres) FOR Date IN (' + @cols1 + ')) AS p';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5fbdc088b0570012c42b012288827282)